# AJAX data.length to var not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: purl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.length);
    }
});
```

I get an alert with the length count.

but when I do this...

```
$.ajax({
    url: purl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        items = data.length;
    }
});

alert(items);
```

Setting length to global varialbe, it doesn't want to play nice.  Thoughts?

Comment: The reason you have to use a callback function is not because jQuery wanted to make your code purposefully ugly, but because the I/O happens asynchronously and the result can only be guaranteed to exist when the callback is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AJAX portion doesn't happen instantaneously; the `alert` takes place before the AJAX callback has time to set the new value for `items`.

As of jQuery 1.5, `$.ajax` returns an object that implements the Promises interface. As such, you can call the `.done` method anytime you need to be sure that the promise has resolved prior to executing your code:

```
​var promise = $.ajax({/*...*/});

promise.done(function(data){
    // Only works if the promise is resolved
});
```

As an example, suppose we created a deferred object directly:

```
var promise = $.Deferred();
```

We then told it not to resolve until after five seconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    promise.resolve("Foo");
}, 5000);
```

But then we bound a handler to respond to clicks on the `document` object:

```
$(document).on("click", function () {
    promise.done(function(data){
        alert("Data is " + data);
    });
});
```

Note that we are putting our alert within an anonymous function, and passing it to `promise.done` to be executed only *after* the promise has been resolved.

This builds up a queue until that promise is resolved. If I click four times in those first five seconds, nothing will happen, but as soon as that promise resolves I will see four alert boxes appear, one after another.

Now that the promise is resolved, any further clicks (after the 5 second wait) will result in immediate action.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w7swE/1/

Comment: So the goal is to just set `items` for use elsewhere.  Is there a way to tell `alert` or whever else I want to use to wait for AJAX callback?

Comment: @Plummer Yes, you can call the next function in the process from within your `success` function, or you could use a promise, and give it some code to execute when the promise is resolved.

Comment: @Plummer Someday, we all will ;) Until then, we've got eachother.

Answer (score 3):

Store a reference to the jqXHR (which also acts just like a promise object), you can then use that to get the data later.

```
var items = $.ajax({
    url: purl,
    dataType: 'json'
});

items.done(function(data){
    alert(data.length);
});

// ... somewhere else, such as in a click event
$("#someEl").click(function(){
    items.done(function(data){
        alert(data.length);
    });
});
```

any time you need the data, add a done callback to `items` and use the data within that callback.

Comment: Woah, woah, woah, woah.  I can set an AJAX call to a global variable and then reference all that hogwash with one word?

Comment: Yes. :) Note however it doesn't re-request the data every time you use it, you're simply requesting access to the existing data when it is ready.

Comment: But if I had it set as a variable inside a parent function, everytime that function is run, will it run the request?  ie, instead of global var, it's a var inside of a function.

Comment: If it is inside of a function and you return $.ajax() from the function, yes. You would just do `theFunction().done(handler)`